# Flutter: Is it possible to have multiple CameraControllers?

Tags: flutter, camera

We are developing an app to analyse an image stream from the camera plugin
`controller.startImageStream((CameraImage img)`
We want to record at the same time using `controller.startRecording()`
The stream would stop streaming if a second controller is made.

Is there a way to record while having an open image stream?

Comment: So apparently it's not supported. What we did was saving each CameraImage as jpg, then use the package FFMPEG to concatenate the files. It takes about 20 seconds for a 60 seconds video on a OnePlus 7t. Next step is to add audio...

Answer (score 0):

It's supported on current camera package:

```dart
controller.startVideoRecording(onAvailable: (CameraImage image) {

});
```